# Navigation animation using JS and SCSS, can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am trying to create a nav that contains 2 elements (left and right). I would like both elements to move in from their respective edges of the screen, meeting in the middle to create a full screen nav. Could anyone shed some light on where I'm going wrong?

So far I have managed to get each box to move individually but not both at the same time. I gave them both separate ID's within their nav class thinking this would allow me to manipulate their postioning in different ways when the function is called that toggles 'expanded' but again this hasnt worked.

This is my HTML Structure:

```
<div class="nav-toggle">
<div class="nav-toggle-bar"></div>
</div>
<nav id="left" class="nav">
</nav>
<nav id="right" class="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Here is an part of my SCSS:

```
.nav {  
background: $nav-background;
color: $nav-color;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 2rem;
height: 100vh;
padding: 6rem 2rem 2rem 2rem;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: $nav-width;
z-index: $z-nav;
ul {
    @include center-vertically;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} 
}
#right{
@include transition(right 0.5s ease);
right: -$nav-width;
&.expanded { right: 0; }
}
#left{
@include transition(left 0.5s ease);
left: -$nav-width;
&.expanded { left: 0; }
}
```

And this is my JS:

```
(function() {

var hamburger = {
    navToggle: document.querySelector('.nav-toggle'),
    nav: document.querySelector('nav'),

    doToggle: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.navToggle.classList.toggle('expanded');
        this.nav.classList.toggle('expanded');
    }
};

hamburger.navToggle.addEventListener('click', function(e) { hamburger.doToggle(e); });

}());
```

This is the codepen I have been working on: https://codepen.io/matthewoproctor/pen/YmxZPQ

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach with the two IDs and the shared classname is perfect, as is your SCSS. The problem here is actually pretty simple: `hamburger.nav` is using `document.querySelector`, which only selects the first element with the `nav` class. Instead, you should use `document.querySelectorAll`. Then you just have to tweak the `doToggle` function to loop through all elements with the `nav` class.

```
(function() {

    var hamburger = {
        navToggle: document.querySelector('.nav-toggle'),
        nav: document.querySelectorAll('nav'),

        doToggle: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.navToggle.classList.toggle('expanded');
            this.nav.forEach(n => n.classList.toggle('expanded'));
        }
    };

    hamburger.navToggle.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    hamburger.doToggle(e);
  });

}());
```